# Finding the value of $\cos (1+i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

The task is to calculate $\cos (1+i) $ and represent it in the algebraic form $ x+ iy$.

I've tried to use the definition: $ \cos z= \frac{\exp(iz)+\exp(-iz)}{2}$ ,

but i don't know how to get to the $x+iy$ form from that. Maybe I should somehow use the the series expansion of cosinus function?

Comment: Use the angle addition formula. A few methods are listed here: [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html).

Comment: Try plugging in the complex number directly into the formula you have tried to use and then use that fact that $e^{i \theta}=\cos( \theta)+ i\sin (\theta)$

Comment: $$\cos(x+iy)=\cos x\cos iy-\sin x\sin iy=\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos z=\dfrac{e^{i(1+i)}+e^{-i(1+i)}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos z=\dfrac{e^{i-1}+e^{-i+1}}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos z=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^i}{e}+e\cdot e^{-i}}{2}$$
Now use the fact that : 
$$e^i=\cos1+i\sin1$$
This will help you in separating out the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

Vic has a good start.
$$
\cos(1+i) = \cos(1)\cos(i) - \sin(1)\sin(i)
= \cos(1)\cosh(1) - i \sin(1)\sinh(1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

So we now that 
$$ cos(1+i)=cos(1)cos(i)-sin(1)(i) $$ $\Rightarrow $